# MySQL Syntax for SQLite Syntax

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I've started using SQLite for my Android applications. What I would like to know is where I can find a list of queries to use, are they the same for MySQL, and would I be able to use similar queries from MySQL?

Comment: Most queries will be similar, but no one can give you a complete tutorial inside a single answer. Start translating, and if you get stuck on translating a concrete one, that is a better time to ask here.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html

Comment: CONCAT* functions do not work in SQlit, they should be replaced with ||. Pipes must be enabled in Mysql using PIPES_AS_CONCAT flag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite provides a pretty good implementation of the SQL standard. Check out the syntax [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html). There is a prominent link in the first paragraph that describes omissions.

EDIT: No stored procedures or functions. You can mimic these in your code at runtime, however, using prepared statements

Comment: Do you know if you an create functions like MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

List of queries? You would need to use '[SQLiteDatabase.query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)' set of methods to query your SQLite database in your Android app. There would be SQLite specific SQL that you would need to consider while migrating your MySQL queries.